How to randomize the location of a RectangularNode?
I want to optimize the location of a random PolygonalArea, and in order to do that, I must create it dynamically via code. However, when I use the following:
var n = new RectangularNode();
n.setVisible(true);
n.setPos(20, 20, 0);
n.setSize(500, 500);
n.setFillColor(new Color(40, 40, 40));
level.add(n)

I get the error message:
level : Markup element is already initialized and cannot be modified. Please use constructor without arguments, perform setup and finally call initialize() function.

But when I create a new level object to put the RectangularNode in, it doesn't show up in the simulation. Could anybody help?

Solution
var n = new RectangularNode();
n.setVisible(true);
n.setPos(20, 20, 0);
n.setSize(500, 500);
n.setFillColor(new Color(40, 40, 40));
Level level = new Level(this, "myLevel", SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, 0);
level.add(n);
presentation.add(level);


This worked! As a follow up, suppose I have PedWait node in my graph, how would I make the location node of that PedWait object this rectangle I just created? In the built-in LSP, I couldn't find such a function or attribute.
